# Can you put a basic command line java program on the cloud?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, cloud, hosting

I currently have a simple java command line program that i want to put up on the cloud in which users can play blackjack on the command line. Is their any cloud services that i can use the same java code that i currently have or will i need to rewrite the code for a specific engine. I looked into Google App engine https://developers.google.com/appengine/ but was a bit unsure as to whether it could be done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what is a "cloud". There are different kinds of service models in cloud (read about SaaS, IaaS and PaaS at [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing)).

You can deploy a command line program on IaaS cloud like Amazon EC2. Amazon EC2 instance is a remote server you can use for doing pretty much anything you want to do on a remote server. Assuming you started one EC2 instance and installed your command line game on that instance, you will have to open the login on that box for your users. You will have to make some arrangement for your users to register. You will have to create a command line login (a shell account) on that server for every user who registers to play the game. Your users will have to telnet or SSH to that EC2 instance using the login you created when the users register for playing the game. Therefore, theoretically it can be done. However, people don't take that route for many reasons, one of them being, all users are not familiar with telnet or SSH terminals. Another major reason is security concerns. Therefore deploying the command line game on EC2 instance and allowing users to telnet/SSH to that instance for playing the game is not a practical option.

It is reasonable to expect every computer user to be familiar with browser. Therefore you should make your game available on a browser. Deploy your game on a remote server and allow the users to play the game on their browser.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. 


Am i correct in saying that i could create 1 account for all users, this login would have little to no permissions and which has the game launched upon login.The game could then connect to a database to save their in game username and scores?

Creating the game for a browser makes more sense but i think this would involve rewriting the code in JavaScript? Which is my second approach if i cannot re-use the current java code

Comment: No, you cannot have one login for all users. How do you identify the users if all of them have the same login? In any case, I have already mentioned that approach has multiple problems and security risks. Best is to port your game to run in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a few classes and command line you can try [runnable.com](http://runnable.com/Java)

It's not "cloud" platform, just code execution, but it will probably be enough for demonstrating small command line program.

Comment: Please 'enter link description there' ^^